# Strip only letters

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a huge excel sheet with everything in a single column but it contains data in the following format:

```
L 3247 3247 0000 U NO CICS 06/30/10 NO NO XSYS3 09/29/08 . NO NO ADM SMK D
3618 3618 0000 U NO CICS 12/21/15 NO NO XSYS3 10/05/09 . NO NO ADM SMK D
3024 3024 0000 U NO CICS 12/28/15 NO NO XSYS3 07/09/07 . NO NO CLK SMK D
2313 2313 0000 U NO CICS 06/12/15 NO NO NO 10/04/06 . NO NO CLK SMK D
M 3247 3247 0000 U NO CICS 10/28/14 NO NO XSYS3 07/28/04 . NO NO ADM SMK D
3046 3046 0000 U NO CICS 12/23/15 NO NO NO 01/13/09 . NO NO ADM SMK D
3648 3648 0000 U NO CICS 12/29/15 NO NO XSYS3 10/05/09 . NO NO ADM SMK D
3265 3265 0000 U NO CICS 11/23/15 NO NO NO 12/02/08 . NO NO MGT SMK D
V 3224 3224 0000 U NO CICS 12/16/15 NO NO XSYS3 10/09/04 . NO NO MGT SMK D
3261 3261 0000 U NO CICS 12/16/15 NO NO XSYS3 10/05/09 . NO NO MGT SMK D
```

I need to strip the letter and spaces from teh rows that start with anything other than a number

I have so far tried using a simple formula such as:

```
=IF(LEFT(C1,1)>9,IF(LEFT(C1,1)<9,RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-2),C1))
```

This looks to me like it should strip the first 2 chracters of every line over "9" and do nothing for any line that is less than "9" but it does nothing at all.

Comment: So now what I've done is create a reference column that has the formula:
    
    =MID(C1,2,1) = " "

This gives me true or false in that column. I am then using the next column to do:

    =IF(D14="TRUE",RIGHT(C14,LEN(C14)-2),IF(D14="FALSE",C14*1))

This also does not seem to quite work though. I get the correct value for all FALSE entries but all TRUE entries in column C show as "FALSE"

I am very confused now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to tackle this problem.  I've shown two below, both of which could be done completely different.

**Formula**

```
=IF(IFERROR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),FALSE),A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2))
```

Formula is in column B
[image]

---

**VBA**

```
Sub stripAlpha()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wks.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wks.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3))

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsNumeric(Left(cell, 1)) Then
            cell.Value = Right(cell, Len(cell) - 2)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Results are in original column (caution, overwrites data.  No undo so *Save* first)

[image]

Comment: The VBA results in:

"Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"

At line:  cell.Value = Right(cell, Len(cell) - 2)

Comment: Change the lastRow to `wks.range("A1").End(xlDown).row`

Comment: @mrbungle good catch, I had test data in col C so I didn't catch that error.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to reflect data being in column C.  Note that the `rng` column changed from 1 to 3 and the `lastrow` is back to "C1"

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using part of what I was already doing.

I took column D and put in:

```
=MID(C1,2,1) = " "
```

This gave me TRUE or FALSE in that column

In E I then used:

```
=IF(LEFT(D1,1)="T",MID(C1,3,255),C1)
```

To strip out the first 2 characters from any row that has TRUE in column D

:)

I plan on converting this to VBA for later automation but this is the simple formula way for now

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B1,1))),B1,RIGHT(B1,(LEN(B1)-2)))`.

Comment: Opps, I see portland runner and I were on the same track